How do I load an image into the leaflet map component instead of OpenStreetMaps?
I've seen people loading normal images into leaflet maps and then you're able to zoom in and out on that image, but I'm struggling to find code on how to load an image into the map.
I know it's definitely possible somehow. Here's an example of a leaflet map with an image that I found online:

And here's the HTML that is rendered for the above image on leaflet map:
<div class="h-[400px] w-full rounded-md lg:h-[600px] lg:w-[600px] leaflet-container leaflet-touch leaflet-retina leaflet-fade-anim leaflet-grab leaflet-touch-drag leaflet-touch-zoom"
    tabindex="0" style="background: rgb(24, 24, 27); z-index: 0; position: relative; outline: none;">
    <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
        <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane"></div>
        <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-overlay-pane"><img class="leaflet-image-layer leaflet-zoom-animated"
                src="https://data.spotguessr.com/maps/csgo/inferno.jpg" alt=""
                style="z-index: 1; transform: translate3d(44px, 44px, 0px); width: 512px; height: 512px;"></div>
        <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-shadow-pane"></div>
        <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane"></div>
        <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tooltip-pane"></div>
        <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-popup-pane"></div>
        <div class="leaflet-proxy leaflet-zoom-animated"
            style="transform: translate3d(256px, -256px, 0px) scale(0.25);"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="leaflet-control-container">
        <div class="leaflet-top leaflet-left"></div>
        <div class="leaflet-top leaflet-right"></div>
        <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-left">
            <div class="leaflet-control-zoom leaflet-bar leaflet-control"><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-in" href="#"
                    title="Zoom in" role="button" aria-label="Zoom in" aria-disabled="false"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">+</span></a><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-out leaflet-disabled" href="#"
                    title="Zoom out" role="button" aria-label="Zoom out" aria-disabled="true"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">−</span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-right"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="relative m-4 text-2xl font-semibold tracking-widest text-slate-100"
        style="z-index: 1000; font-family: Rajdhani;">INFERNO</p>
</div>

So you can see they have a normal .jpg image that is loaded into it somehow.
This is my image that I'd like to load into my leaflet map:

It's a normal .png image that I'd like to load into the TWebLeafletMaps component in TMS WEB Core using Delphi code.
If needs be, I'm willing to use an example that is a mix between JavaScript and Delphi also through the asm code block.
How can I do this?

Use any HTML's element .innerHTML property to assign any content. Examples: #1, #2, #3.
